# I appended data to a list from a pandas dataframe and am not able to use list comprehension on it?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, list-comprehension

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sl No':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Content':['abcd','efhg','acsd','drtsf','dfthsrfv','ftyjdrtg','dthrsgae','awefawef','thr','hdthrt']}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
all_data =[]
all_data.append(dataframe.Content.values)
```

now if I try to add a list comprehension like below I get an error.

```
txt_1 = " ".join(v for v in all_data if v not in string.punctuation).lower()
```

*TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not numpy.ndarray*

Can any one explain how to overcome this , expect other than using .extend() command?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52153208/edit) to include your desired output.

Comment: Were you looking for extend instead of append? Also, that's a generator expression or generator comprehension, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Why do you want to extend an existing list when you can just do `list(df.Content.values)`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `all_data`:

```
In [679]: all_data
Out[679]: 
[array(['abcd', 'efhg', 'acsd', 'drtsf', 'dfthsrfv', 'ftyjdrtg',
        'dthrsgae', 'awefawef', 'thr', 'hdthrt'], dtype=object)]
```

That's a list containing one array.  That means that the `v` in your comprehension will be this array, not one of the words in the array.

`extend` instead of `append` unpacks the array when adding it to the list.

Another option is add a layer to select the array from the list, and then loop, `for v in all_data[0]`.

Your list comprehension wouldn't work if you'd `appended` a list of words to the list either.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this. Since `all_data` is a list containing an array of strings, you'll need to actually access the array(s) rather than `all_data`.

Assuming that there might be more than one element in `all_data`, you could use a nested list comprehension version of the code you posted:

```
txt_1 = " ".join(s for v in all_data for s in v if s not in string.punctuation).lower()
```

On the other hand, if you just want the values from `dataframe['Content']`, you have two options:

```
txt_2 = " ".join(v for v in all_data[0] if v not in string.punctuation).lower()
txt_3 = " ".join(v for v in dataframe.Content if v not in string.punctuation).lower()
```

Option 2 specifically refers to the array stored within `all_data` at position 0, whereas option 3 bypasses the need for the list by accessing `dataframe['Content']` directly.